# SugarCRM many-to-one relationship from custom module to Target/Prospect not working

Tags: sugarcrm

We are using SugarCRM CE 6.5.16

We created a custom module with a many-to-one relationship to the Targets module.

When creating a custom record, the page has a link to select a Target. Clicking on it opens a subpanel and allows me to select one; closing the subpanel. The relationship field should now be populated with the Target's name, but it remains empty.

This seems to happen only with the Targets module. I specifically tested that relationships to Contacts and Leads work correctly.

Nothing is logged to sugarcrm.log

(I suspected it could have something to do with the fact that Target is named Prospect in the back-end. So I changed the name of the Targets module to Prospects from the admin interface. But still could not get it working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue for this problem in the SugarCRM issue tracker [Defect 25478](https://web.sugarcrm.com/support/issues/f08389e4-2e76-21b3-24cb-48f5b3a26583)

See also SugarCRM community discussion [Many-to-one relationship from custom module to Target/Prospect not working](https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/many_to_one_relationship_from_custom_module_to_target_prospect_not_working)